# Set contains for user defined classes using __hash__ function

Tags: python, hash, set, python-internals, magic-methods

Given:

```
class T:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1234

t1 = T()
t2 = T()

my_set = { t1 }
```

I would expect the following to print `True`:

```
print t2 in my_set
```

Isn't this supposed to print `True` because `t1` and `t2` have the same hash value. How can I make the `in` operator of the `set` use the given hash function?

Comment: t1 and t2 are not equal, they're two different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define an `__eq__` method because only instances that are identical `a is b` or equal `a == b` (besides having the same `hash`) will be recognized as equal by `set` and `dict`:

```
class T:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1234
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

t1 = T()
t2 = T()

my_set = { t1 }

print(t2 in my_set)  # True
```

The [data model on `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (and [the same documentation page for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)) explains this:

> `__hash__`
>
> Called by built-in function `hash()` and for operations on members of hashed collections including `set`, `frozenset`, and `dict. __hash__()` should return an integer. **The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value;** it is advised to mix together the hash values of the components of the object that also play a part in comparison of objects by packing them into a tuple and hashing the tuple.
>
> **If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either**; if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).
>
> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies both that `x is y and hash(x) == hash(y)`.

(Emphasis mine)

Note: In Python 2 you can also implement a `__cmp__` method instead of `__eq__`.

Answer (score 1):

In psuedocode, the logic for *set.__contains__()* when called by `x in s` is roughly:

```
h = hash(s)                          # This uses your class's __hash__()
i = h % table_size                   # This logic is internal to the hash table
if table[i] is empty: return False   # Nothing found in the set 
if table[i] is x: return True        # Identity implies equality
if hash(table[i]) != h: return False # Hash mismatch implies inequality
return table[i] == x                 # This needs __eq__() in your class
```