# Trying to add a pydantic model to a set gives unhashable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have the following code

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = "Jane Doe"


def add_user(user: User):
    a = set()
    a.add(user)
    return a


add_user(User(id=1))
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'User'
```

Is there a way this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to implement an hash function for the class.
You can easily do that by hashing the User's id or name and return it as the hash...

like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = "Jane Doe"

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return self.name.__hash__() # or self.id.__hash__()


def add_user(user: User):
    a = set()
    a.add(user)
    return a


add_user(User(id=1))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This works. Couple of questions: 1. Why is hashing necessary here? 2. Can any attribute be used for hashing?

Comment: 1) hashing is necessary because the set data structure uses hashes internally to store the values. 2) the attribute should be a "special" hash-able object, because we want the fewest possible number of hash collusions.  ***currently you don't have __eq__ implemented so two users with the same attribute values won't be considered equal for the set, it instead would compare their object id. I believe that each user id should be special so you can implement __eq__ using it... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42061019/set-contains-for-user-defined-classes-using-hash-function).

Comment: If you don't have a unique identifier or want to consider the whole thing, take model dump as json string and hash it

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), pydantic only supports automatic hashability for *immutable* aka *frozen* containers. Simply [declare `frozen=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.frozen) for the class:

```
class User(BaseModel, frozen=True):
    id: int
    name: str = "Jane Doe"
```

The generated class then automatically takes all fields into account when comparing or hashing instances. This is similar to [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) and its `frozen` flag.